# How do MemoryStream handle an assigned buffer?

Tags: .net, allocation, memorystream

Let's say that I'm assigning a buffer in the `MemoryStream` constructor (buffer, offset, count).

How do the `MemoryStream` handle it? Will it copy the buffer, or use it? Will it use another buffer (autogrow) if I try to write more bytes than the length of the buffer?

Couldn't find any relevant info at MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63z365ty%28v=VS.90%29.aspx): "Initializes a new *non-resizable* instance of the MemoryStream class based on the specified region (index) of a byte array." I've used the (buffer) constructor before; it uses the array as the storage, with no copying involved.

Answer (score 1):

[Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) is set to the length of the specified byte array. The new stream can be written to, but is not resizable.